# Delete HTML Table Rows Using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

How do I delete HTML table rows using PHP?

The javascript inside my PHP keeps breaking my table's formatting and I have no idea why. Can anybody help me out?

```
if(checkValue($_POST['hasBeenSubmitted'])) {
switch($_POST['hasBeenSubmitted']) {
case 'yes':

         ?>
         //THESE SCRIPT TAGS KEEP BREAKING MY PHP
         <script>
                 var myTable = document.getElementById("table");
                 var rowCount = myTable.rows.length;
                 for (var x=rowCount-1; x>0; x--) {
                     myTable.deleteRow(x);
                 }
         </script>
         <?php

         $updatedapplicants = $db->query($query1);
         populateTable($updatedapplicants);
     break;
}
}
```

Comment: so where in your document are you stuffing that script block? You can't just have php output it ANYWHERE in an html document.

Comment: The `<script>` tags are not the problem as they are not within a PHP block, if your code is correct. What is the exact error? Also, @Fred-ii- - This is not related to MySQL

Comment: It breaks the formatting of my HTML table when run.

Comment: It matters WHERE in the html you're ouputting that, e.g. `<script>...</script><html><body>....</body></html>` produces an illegal document. And if your table has row/col spans as well, deleting arbitrary rows can really muck things up too

Comment: You may also be getting confused about the life-cycle of PHP: PHP prepares an entire page of output, sends it to the browser, and exits; **then** the browser renders the whole page, and any JavaScript code starts. When you submit a form, the whole thing starts again, and you are creating a brand new piece of output, so you shouldn't need to tell JS to remove the rows, just don't output them in the first place!